# suggest tool for UI prototyping on Android - AppInventor, other?

Tags: android, user-interface, prototyping

I am looking for a prototyping tool for Android - what is your experience, is [MIT AppInventor](http://www.appinventor.mit.edu/) (former Google AppInventor) worth a look?

Can you suggest any other (better) prototyping tool I should be aware of?

I am quite at home with developing applications in Java, I would just like a tool that would allow me to conduct early user experience testing. What is your experience, is using prototyping tool worth the extra learning or should I just write the app?

Comment: I would say just write an application with your screens with no or minimal fuctionality. Writing XML layouts in Eclipse Android UI designer is not difficult. If you do the same using some other tool you're doing the work twice and can not be sure you will be able to implement the same for Android

Comment: Alex, care to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one for online generator

- Android Asset Studio http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

If you want to create android design mock up, Pencil is a good one

- Pencil GUI prototyping tool - http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx
- Download the pencil stencils at: http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/list

Source: http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/

Comment: Neither is exactly what I had in mind, but I use Pencil already (very useful!) and Android Asset looks interesting too - thanks for the links!

Answer (score 2):

I would say just write an application with your screens with no or minimal functionality. Writing XML layouts in Eclipse Android UI designer is not difficult. If you do the same using some other tool you're doing the work twice and can not be sure you will be able to implement the same for Android

Answer (score 1):

Preview mode of IntelliJ IDEA is really useful and allows you to get look and feel quickly
while autoring xml layout

Answer (score 1):

To get high quality feedback in user testing, you'd want to use realistic prototypes with native controls that run on real devices. Static image based "click dummies" are useful but far from enough.

Check out [jimu Mirror](http://jimulabs.com/) and [Mirror.js](http://jimulabs.com/mirrorjs-preview/), which make it easier to create such prototypes compared to writing a full app.

Mirror is a UI dev tool that gives you live previews of Android UI on real devices. You can use a simple XML file to fill your ListView (or other views) with sample data so the screens look exactly the same as if the app is finished. It behaves the same as well because it's an app running on the device.

Built on top of the liveliness of Mirror, Mirror.js lets you prototype the dynamic part of the UI: animations, screen transitions, navigation between screens etc. You use Android's XML resources and a bit of JavaScript to make these prototypes and **much of the code can be reused in development**. When you are done, you can share your work as an APK.

Full disclosure, I'm one of the creators of this tool.